# How to get ul structure from HTML

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I am making a configuration page, that splits a category tree over 3 columns for easy browsing like:

```
**Column 1**            **Column 2**             **Column3**  
   Category1               Category3                Category5
    *SubCategory1*         Category4                  *SubCategory5*
   Category2                 *SubCategory4*           *SubCategory6*
     *SubCategory2*        etc.
     *SubCategory3*
```

I am using jsp, jquery, and struts2.
What I am trying to do is configure the order in which categories/subcategories are displayed.
Now I show the structure like that, and I am able to drag them from a column to another, sort the categories of a column and sort the subcategories, using jquery and modifying directly the HTML, but I don't realize how to get the data of the modified structure to persist it over my DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had to do something similar on a personal project of mine, but never ended up actually using the feature I was writing it for, but here's the code I used:

```
function refactor() {
    var array = jQuery.makeArray($('ul#remapped > li:not(.target)'));
    var mappedArray = jQuery.map(array, function(i) {
        var merged = $(i).find('ul.merge > li:not(.target) > span');
        return {
            column: $(i).children('span').text(),
            merged: jQuery.map(jQuery.makeArray(merged), function(mi) { return { column: mi.innerText }; })
        };
    });

    var xml = '<columns>';
    jQuery.each(mappedArray, function(index, item) {
        xml += '\n\t<column>';
        xml += '\n\t\t<name>' + item.column + '</name>';
        if (item.merged.length > 0) {
            xml += '\n\t\t\t<merged>';
            jQuery.each(item.merged, function(mindex, mitem) {
                xml += '\n\t\t\t\t<name>' + mitem.column + '</name>';
            });
            xml += '\n\t\t\t</merged>';
        }
        xml += '\n\t</column>';
    });
    xml += '\n</columns>';

    $('div#result').load('/Tools/Csv/Refactor', { mapping: xml });
}
```

Basically, the user would use the UI to drag and drop as they please to create the structure they want. Then, they click a button which executes this method.

The $('ul#remapped') query is the element (in my code) that contained the new structure, and then I did some additional querying, again, based on my DOM structure, to extract the values I needed from the DOM and generate an XML string, which was then posted to the server.

I'm sure this isn't *exactly* what you need, but I'm hoping its close enough that you can modify it for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming the structure gets modified by drag and drop. You can make an ajax call every time a change in the structure occurs and update the data in CategorySucategories table you have. I don't know your db structure, so I made an assumption about that too.